# Excel VBA User-Defined Function: Get Cell in Sheet Function was Called In

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I have a user-defined function in Excel that I run in multiple sheets.  I am trying to use `Cells(i, j)` to pull the value of cells by their row and column **in the sheet in which my function is called**.  Instead, `Cells(i, j)` pulls the value of cell [i,j] in the **active sheet** when I hit the 'Calculate Now' button, and auto-calculation does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

The full function is below, not sure if it's needed to answer my question.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Option Compare Text

Function recordString(ByVal width As Integer, ByVal height As Integer, ByVal firstCell As Range) As String
    Application.Volatile

    Dim tempString As String
    tempString = ""
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    For i = firstCell.Row To firstCell.Row + height - 1
        For j = firstCell.Column To firstCell.Column + width - 1
            If IsEmpty(Cells(i, j)) Then
                tempString = tempString & "0"
            Else
                tempString = tempString & "1"
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    recordString = tempString
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Application.Caller.

This will return the value in cell A1 of the sheet the function is entered to:

```
Public Function DisplayCaller() As String

    DisplayCaller = Application.Caller.Parent.Cells(1, 1)

End Function
```

This will return the name of the calling sheet:

```
Public Function DisplayCaller() As String

    DisplayCaller = Application.Caller.Parent.Name

End Function
```

For more info:
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/sheetref.htm

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  That's what I get for thinking the Cells function would work intuitively.